# Why are this previews in unity material different?

Tags: unity-game-engine, light, materials

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W3OK.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OX3g.png)

Each of versions are 2022 and 2019.

I exported prefabs from other projects and imported them but previews of inspector are different. Why?
Is it related to lighting or reflection probe?

Comment: Do the materials look different when used by you in a scene? Because if not it just looks like a different lighting setup in the preview render. As long as they behave equally, my bet is that the thumbnail generator uses a different scene setup in 2022 than in 2019.